# Getting weird errors for python script on lines that don't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, search, browser

I wrote this script a while ago that will search the definition of all words in a searches.txt file, it was used for school vocabulary projects. With the start of the new school year, I needed to recover it to use it again. I'm getting weird errors that seem like its a problem with my python install but I get nothing similar to it in other py programs, I might also not have a library installed. The code and the errors are below, let me know what you think the problem is. Thanks in advance!

**Code**

```
from subprocess import call
import re
import sys

links = []

filename = 'C:\\Users\\TestoW\\Documents\\Coding\\definition-search\\searches.txt'

try:
    with open(filename) as linkListFile:
        for line in linkListFile:
            link = line.strip()
            if link != '':
                if re.match('http://.+|https://.+|ftp://.+|file://.+', link.lower()):
                    links.append(link)
                else:
                    links.append('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/' + link)
                    #https://www.google.com/search?q=
                    #https://www.dictionary.com/browse/
                    #http://maps.google.com/?q=
except IOError:
    print ('Failed to open the file "%s".\nExiting.')
    sys.exit()

print (links)
call(["open"]+links)
```

**seaches.txt example**

```
Matter
Energy
Temperature
Non-Newtonian Liquid 
Sublimation
Deposition
```

**WINDOWS ERROR**

```
['https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Matter', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Energy', 'https://www.dictionary.com/bro
wse/Temperature', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Non-Newtonian Liquid', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Sublimati
on', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Deposition', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Melting Point', 'https://www.dic
tionary.com/browse/Boiling Point', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Phase Change', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/
Endothermic', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Exothermic', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Compound', 'https://www
.dictionary.com/browse/Intrinsic Property', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Extrinsic Property', 'https://www.diction
ary.com/browse/Crystallization', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Centrifugation', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/
Distillation', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Chromatography', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Filtration', 'http
s://www.dictionary.com/browse/Homogeneous', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/Heterogeneous']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TestoW\Documents\Coding\definition-search\AutoLookUp.py", line 26, in <module>
    call(["open"]+links)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

C:\Users\TestoW>
```

Comment: It's saying that it can't find the `open` command.

Comment: ...and "open" isn't a valid Windows command so it's looking for a file by that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me to open the links in the list:

```
for lnk in links:
   call(["start"]+[lnk], shell=True)
```

-- Update --

Found another way to open the links without opening a cmd window.

```
import win32com.client
sh = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
for lnk in links:
   sh.run(lnk)
```

Comment: Thanks that works, is there a way to not open a cmd instance for every search?